# android chat thumbnail position

Tags: java, android

I have a conversation page with bubble and thumbnail user image, I have problem with thumbnail position: when I send text thumbnail must show on the right and when my friend sent text his thumbnail must show on the left

My XML item is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/user_four"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:textColor="#2e2e2e"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my Java code is :

```
public class ChatArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comment> {

    private TextView countryName;
    private List<Comment> countries = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    private LinearLayout wrapper;


    @Override
    public void add(Comment object) {
        countries.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    public ChatArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.countries.size();
    }

    public Comment getItem(int index) {
        return this.countries.get(index);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_chat, parent, false);
        }

        wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

        Comment coment = getItem(position);

        countryName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);

        countryName.setText(coment.comment);

        countryName.setBackgroundResource(coment.left ? R.drawable.other_bubble : R.drawable.own_bubble);
        wrapper.setGravity(coment.left ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);


        return row;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeToBitmap(byte[] decodedByte) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know in getView() method that the text is your's or your friend's you can change gravity attribute to left or right, depending on the condition, of the linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use seperate layout for left and right then inflate it with the correct layout in your get view